# Headphones and speakers connected on the rear | Simultaneously sound

Tags: audio, speakers, sound-card, headphones

I have connected my headphones to the rear green port, and speakers to the rear black port. I want to use both of them just as simple 2:1 stereo, to play Simultaneously the same sound in headphones and speakers. Speakers were playing only when I set mode to Quadrophonic, which wasn't what I expected. How do I need to set up this to achieve what I described?

Answer (score -1):

I found this site:
https://www.reaper-x.com/2012/02/13/how-to-remap-retasking-realtek-onboard-jacks-ports/
In my case Line-In was "Pin1a", changed the value of it to: "03 00 00 00" and it's working great :)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.